# How to pass values to the list which exist in another class

Tags: c#, .net, oop

These are my classes

```
   public class Competitor
    {
        public string Team { get; set; }
        public string Win { get; set; }
    }

    public class CompetitorsClass
    {
        public int ActiveCompetitors { get; set; }
        public List<Competitor> Competitors { get; set; }
        public int TotalCompetitors { get; set; }
        public bool HasWinOdds { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public int EventID { get; set; }
        public int ParentEventID { get; set; }
        public string MainEvent { get; set; }
        public CompetitorsClass Competitors { get; set; }
        public string EventStatus { get; set; }
        public bool IsSuspended { get; set; }
        public bool AllowBets { get; set; }
    }
```

Here i am passing data into the Root class. How can i pass values to CompetitorsClass Competitors. Can anyone tell me how to do it and any example similar to this one? I know it may be basic stuff for most of you but i am new to C# and learning .

```
    var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, RootObject>>>(json);

    foreach (var root in obj2)
    {
        int count = root.Value.Count;
        foreach (var child in root.Value)
        {
            RootObject ob = new RootObject();
            ob.EventID = child.Value.EventID;
            ob.EventStatus = child.Value.EventStatus;
            CompetitorsClass cs = new CompetitorsClass();
            cs.ActiveCompetitors = 0;
            cs.HasWinOdds = false;
            cs.TotalCompetitors = 2;

            //  cs.Competitors
            // cs.Competitors = ob.Competitors;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to approach the problem:

1. Simply assign the collection, something like:

   ```
   CompetitorsClass cs = new CompetitorsClass();
   cs.ActiveCompetitors = 0;
   cs.Competitors = myList; //or new List<Competitor>() if you don't have it yet.
   ```
2. Pass in the constructor and assign:

   ```
   public class CompetitorsClass
   {
      public CompetitorsClass(List<Competitor> competitors)
      {
           Competitors = competitors;
      }
      ...
   }

   cs = new CompetitorsClass(myList);
   ```

The second is generally preferred, because it guarantees that the variable was initialized, instead of relying on the default value (`null` in this case).

To get to the existing object's Competitors list, you would write:

```
ob.Competitors.Competitors //This is "myList" in my examples
```

Answer (score 0):

`RootObject` has `Competitors` properties and it's type is `CompetitorsClass`.

You can use that properties:

```
cs.Competitors = ob.Competitors.Competitors;
```